# Functions don't get executed form initState()

Tags: flutter, dart

I have been learning to deal with the `async` functions in the flutter. I have defined an `async` function and I have called it for two places 
1. From the `build` function. 
2. From the `initState`. 
 The Functions is when called from the `build` function gets executed and the text is printed to the terminal, however, calling it from the `initstate` no text is logged into the terminal. 
 Here is the Code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(Test());

class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestState createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    random();
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // random();
    return MaterialApp(home: Scaffold(body: Center(child: Text("Wattup"))));
  }

  Future<void> random() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));
    print("I'm Back baby");
  }
}
```

Comment: while in general `super.initState()` should be called first, your code should work - i mean calling `random()` from `initState` - i just verified that a minute ago - a `print()` after `await Future.delayed(....)` is called  and i see it in the log output

Comment: and i am 99% sure that you added `random()` to `initState()` and pressed "hot reload" button, am i right?

Comment: Yes you are right Im hold reloading, although reloading the app somehow works, I'm still not able to understand what is happening under the hood, and the fact that it works on `reload` and not on `hot-reload` is making it all the more confusing

Comment: basically if you do hot-reload `initState` for existing `StatefulWidget` is not called, but if you do hot-restart it is called and your `random()` method is called too

Comment: more here: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/hot-reload#how-to-perform-a-hot-reload - search for `What is the difference between hot reload, hot restart, and full restart?` - they say for example: *"Hot reload loads code changes into the VM and re-builds the widget tree, preserving the app state; it doesn’t rerun main() or initState(). (⌘\ in Intellij and Android Studio, ⌃F5 in VSCode)"*

Comment: Thanks will definitely check out, so as Mentioned by other answers, I don't need to place my functions calls before `super.initsate()` right?

Comment: as i said your function should work if you add it before or after `super.initState()` but the "normal" way is to call `super` stuff first, then your extra code

Comment: Alright, Thanks for the answer!

Comment: sure, your welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call your method after `super.initState` like this:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    random();

  }
```

Comment: Could you please explain what happens when its called before the `super.initState` a under the hood view?

Comment: `initstate` is called when this object is inserted into the tree. If you don't call super.initState first, then nothing will be executed. Look here for more detail: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/initState.html

Comment: actually, in that case `super.initState()` can be called first / in the middle / last - it does not matter where you call it - the good, normal practice is call it first though - for more see what [State.initState](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/2783f8e2e1/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart#L1145) is actually doing

Answer (score 2):

I think, Super.initState() should be called first So, put it in first line. Try this.

Comment: Could you please explain what happens when its called before the `super.initState` a under the hood view?

Comment: When we override any method, it means In parent class method is defined, we just add more things into that, so when super.initState(). it executes parent class initState method, which does all main work, so it is must to call it first only.

Answer (score 2):

The [initState](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/initState.html) method:

> If you override this, make sure your method **starts** with a call to super.initState().

Emphasis mine.

So whatever you do, you need to do it *after* your call to `super.initState();`

Comment: Could you please explain what happens when its called before the `super.initState` a under the hood view?

Comment: Bad things.  Bad enough that they made a notation about it in the docs.  Generally, a framework designer has an idea of how super calls should be ordered, as sometimes the superclass requires the subclass to take action first, and sometimes the other way around.

Answer (score 2):

Try executing the function after the widget has been build like this:

```
    @override
    void initState () {
      WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_){
        random();
      });
      super.initState();
     
    }
```

Or

```
 @override
    void initState () {
      super.initState();
        random();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to print afte 2 sec, then your random function should be like this,

```
 Future<void> random() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2),(){
      print("I'm Back baby");
    });
  }
```

This will print the line after 2 sec, and it doesn't matter if you put it before or after super.init